# Setting the username globally for sfdx, how do I change it back?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

My situation now is that I went ahead and did some changes I shouldn't have done to my sfdx config and now both my default username and my devhubusername are set to my production user, and both are global values.  So when I open up the scratch org, it launches the production Salesforce instead of a scratch org, which is what I want.
how do I unset this?  My config right now when issuing sfdx force:config:list --json is

```
"key": "defaultdevhubusername",
  "location": "Global",
  "value": "*production user name*"
},
{
  "key": "defaultusername",
  "location": "Global",
  "value": "*production user name*"
```

Obviously not an ideal situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the answer by @Phil W. If you want to remove the global value of `defaultdevhubusername`. you can reset it using the below command.

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultdevhubusername= -g
```

It will clear the value.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [config commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_config.htm#cli_reference_force_config):

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=me@my.org defaultdevhubusername=me@myhub.org -g
```

With the -g you set your globals. Setting them "blank" clears the (global) setting (thanks for the reminder Rahul!).